# How to import SimpleImputer from sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I would like to import `SimpleImputer` from sklearn, I have tried the following code:

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
```

However, it gives the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-14ff80a1bb2f> in <module>()
  2 #!pip install -U scikit-learn
  3 #!pip show scikit-learn
  4 from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

 ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\impute\__init__.py in <module>()
  2 import typing
  3 
  4 from ._base import MissingIndicator, SimpleImputer
  5 from ._knn import KNNImputer
  6 

  ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\impute\_base.py in <module>()
 12 
 13 from ..base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
 14 from ..utils.sparsefuncs import _get_median
 15 from ..utils.validation import check_is_fitted
 16 from ..utils.validation import FLOAT_DTYPES

 ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\sparsefuncs.py in <module>()
  6 import scipy.sparse as sp
  7 import numpy as np
  8 from .validation import _deprecate_positional_args
  9 
 10 from .sparsefuncs_fast import (

ImportError: cannot import name '_deprecate_positional_args'
```

The version for my `scikit-learn` is: 0.23.1

Is there any other way to import SimpleImputer or how can I make `from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer` code work?

Comment: Please copy your error from the image into a code fence.

Comment: yes, removed the image

Comment: Much better already! Thank you.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. Maybe it has something to do with your version of Python?

Comment: My version of python is 3.6.5, which one is yours @Ronan?

Comment: @user9463814 3.8.2. That's definitely odd.

Comment: Restart your kernel or shell.